# I am confused on how to add "ranks" to my DeckOfCards lab

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

everyone, I am trying to add an array named ranks containing the ranks of the cards such as 1 having a rank of 1, and the ace having 11 or 1. I already made a face array and suit array, all I need is ranks and I'm confused on how to actually add that to the deck array which gets printed at the end.

```java
public class DeckOfCards{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = {
            "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"
        };

        String[] face = {
            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
        };
        int n = s.length * face.length;
        String[] deck = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < face.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
                deck[s.length*i + j] = face[i] + ", " + s[j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i));
            String temp = deck[r];
            deck[r] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = temp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(deck[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could create card objects, could use a 2D array if you want, etc.

Comment: The word "rank" is usually used for what you call "face": [*The 52-card deck is the most popular deck and includes **13 ranks** of each **suit** with reversible "court" or face cards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card#French_suits).

Comment: The value of 1 or 11 for an Ace is not a feature of the card, it's a feature of the card *game* being played, e.g. Blackjack: [*The **value** of cards two through ten is their pip value (2 through 10). Face cards (Jack, Queen, and King) are all worth ten. Aces can be worth one or eleven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack). As you can see, the word "face" is used for 3 of the 13 "ranks".

Comment: As for your question, it is often a good idea to use `enum` for `Suit` and `Rank`. You can then add a `value` field to the `Rank`. This of course assumes that you've learned about `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Card class which is then added to an arraylist of cards. This class can encapsulate the Rank, Suit and Face information of each card.

```
class Card {
  private ArrayList≤Integer≥ rank = new ArrayList<>();
  private String suit;
  private String face;

  public Card(int newRank, String newSuit, String newFace){
    this.rank.add(newRank);
    this.suit = newSuit;
    this.face = newFace;
  }
  //additional methods, getters/setters.
}
```

You can populate your deck by creating an arraylist of Card.

```
Arraylist<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then add to your deck by iterating through the arrays.

```
for(int j = 0; j < suitArray.length; j++){
    for(int k = 0; k < faceArray.length; k++){
        deck.add(new Card(k, suitArray[j], faceArray[k]));
    }
}
```

This only works for incremental ranks i.e. ACE = 11, King = 10 .. ONE = 1.

If you need different Rank weights, you can try checking the card you would like to assign an additional weight after populating the deck.

```
for(Card c : deck){
 if (c.getName.equals("ACE"))
    c.addRank(11);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to create additional array to store ranks, for example:

```
String[] ranks = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
    "10", "11", "12", "13"};
```

And update deck population to:

```
deck[s.length*i + j] = face[i] + ", " + s[j] + ", rank: " + ranks[i];
```

The better solution will be to create Card class to store all data.